# pandas select rows with no duplicate

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 1 dataframe and I want to select all rows that don't have duplicates

My df:

```
Name     Age
Jp       4
Anna     15
Jp       4
John     10
```

My output should be :

```
Name    Age
Anna     15
John     10
```

I am using Pandas dataframe

any suggestions?

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.  See [How much research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: @Prune: bad as this question is, it's not about duplicate **indices**, so not a dupe of that target. It's about **duplicates in multiple columns.**

Answer (score 1):

You want to drop duplicates across multiple columns:

```
df.drop_duplicates(['Name','Age'])
```

Please see the pandas [documentation on basic methods of dataframes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html).