# Using `drop_duplicates` on a Pandas dataframe isn't dropping rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop-duplicates

**Situation**

I have dataframe similar to below ( although I've removed many of the rows for this example, as evidenced in the 'index' column):

`df`

| index | id | name | last_updated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1518 | Maker | 2022-12-31T03:02:00.000Z |
| 1 | 1518 | Maker | 2022-12-31T02:02:00.000Z |
| 2 | 1518 | Maker | 2022-12-31T14:02:00.000Z |
| 3 | 1518 | Maker | 2022-12-31T16:02:00.000Z |
| 23 | 1518 | Maker | 2022-12-31T17:02:00.000Z |
| 24 | 2280 | Filecoin | 2022-12-31T01:02:00.000Z |
| 25 | 2280 | Filecoin | 2022-12-31T03:01:00.000Z |
| 26 | 2280 | Filecoin | 2022-12-31T02:01:00.000Z |
| 27 | 2280 | Filecoin | 2022-12-31T00:02:00.000Z |
| 47 | 2280 | Filecoin | 2022-12-31T08:02:00.000Z |
| 48 | 4558 | Flow | 2022-12-31T01:02:00.000Z |
| 49 | 4558 | Flow | 2022-12-31T02:01:00.000Z |
| 71 | 4558 | Flow | 2022-12-31T05:02:00.000Z |
| 72 | 5026 | Orchid | 2022-12-31T01:02:00.000Z |
| 73 | 5026 | Orchid | 2022-12-31T03:02:00.000Z |
| 74 | 5026 | Orchid | 2022-12-31T02:01:00.000Z |
| 75 | 5026 | Orchid | 2022-12-31T00:02:00.000Z |

I want a version of the above dataframe but with only 1 row for each `id` parameter. Keeping the last instance.

**This is my code:**

`df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id'], keep='last')`

**Expectation**

That the new df would retain only 4 rows, the 'last' instance for each 'id' value in dataframe `df`.

**Result**

After running the `drop_duplicates` command, the `df` returns the exact same dataframe. Same shape as prior to my `drop_duplicates` attempt.

I've been trying to use this post to sort it out, but obvs there's something I'm not getting right:

[pandas select rows with no duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66215844/pandas-select-rows-with-no-duplicate)

I'd appreciate any input on why the last instance of rows with duplicate 'id' values are not being dropped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id'], keep='last', inplace=True)`. If you don't do this, only a copy is returned. By specifying inplace=True, the dataframe is modified.

See documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you both! That returned the result I wanted. I did get a notice along with the results: `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame`. Is that simply because I'm reusing the same df name? If I change the df name (e.g., `df1 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id'], keep='last', inplace=True)`, then print `df1`, it returns `None`.

Comment: Yes I think it is caused because you use the same name for the df. Maybe this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas. Glad it helped!

Comment: Or you can simply leave the reassignment `df1 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id'], keep='last', inplace=True)` and do `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id'], keep='last', inplace=True)` instead

Comment: @dsx if any of the answers work for you - do not forget to mark it as accepted one (checkmark to the left of the answer)

Comment: Thx! i think I'll keep it simple and go with `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id'], keep='last', inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Either reassign the variable:

```py
str = """
index   id  name    last_updated
0   1518    Maker   2022-12-31T03:02:00.000Z
1   1518    Maker   2022-12-31T02:02:00.000Z
2   1518    Maker   2022-12-31T14:02:00.000Z
3   1518    Maker   2022-12-31T16:02:00.000Z
23  1518    Maker   2022-12-31T17:02:00.000Z
24  2280    Filecoin    2022-12-31T01:02:00.000Z
25  2280    Filecoin    2022-12-31T03:01:00.000Z
26  2280    Filecoin    2022-12-31T02:01:00.000Z
27  2280    Filecoin    2022-12-31T00:02:00.000Z
47  2280    Filecoin    2022-12-31T08:02:00.000Z
48  4558    Flow    2022-12-31T01:02:00.000Z
49  4558    Flow    2022-12-31T02:01:00.000Z
71  4558    Flow    2022-12-31T05:02:00.000Z
72  5026    Orchid  2022-12-31T01:02:00.000Z
73  5026    Orchid  2022-12-31T03:02:00.000Z
74  5026    Orchid  2022-12-31T02:01:00.000Z
75  5026    Orchid  2022-12-31T00:02:00.000Z
"""

csvStringIO = StringIO(str)
df = pd.read_csv(csvStringIO, sep="\t")
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id'], keep='last')
print(df) # 4 rows
```

Or set `inplace` to `True`:

```py
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id'], keep='last', inplace=True)
print(df) # 4 rows
```